# Selenium can't connect to GhostDriver (but only sometimes)

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs, ghostdriver

I've setup a simple webscraping script in Python w/ Selenium and PhantomJS. I've got about 200 URLs in total to scrape. The script runs fine at first then after about 20-30 URLs (it can be more/less as it seems random when it fails and isn't related to any particular URL) I get the following error in python:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'Can not connect to GhostDriver'
```

And my ghostdriver.log:

```
PhantomJS is launching GhostDriver...
[ERROR - 2014-07-04T17:27:37.519Z] GhostDriver - main.fail - {"message":"Could not start Ghost Driver","line":82,"sourceId":140692115795456,"sourceURL":":/ghostdriver/main.js","stack":"Error: Could not start Ghost Driver\n    at :/ghostdriver/main.js:82","stackArray":[{"sourceURL":":/ghostdriver/main.js","line":82}]}
```

I've searched and most of the questions on SO seem to be that they can't even run a single URL. The only other question I've found where the error occurs at the middle of the script is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20309170/selenium-and-phantomjs-error-cannot-connect-to-ghostdriver) and the answer is to upgrade phantomjs to the latest version, which I've done. The other answer simply says to try that URL again and doesn't seem a good solution since the URL could simply fail again.

I am running phantomjs version 1.9.7 and selenium version 2.42.1 on Linux Mint 17 on python 2.7.6

```
for url in ['example.com/1/', 'example.com/2/', 'example.com/3/', .. , ..]:
    user_agent = 'Chrome'
    dcap = dict(DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS)
    dcap['phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent'] = user_agent
    driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path='/usr/bin/phantomjs', desired_capabilities=dcap)
    driver.get(url)
```

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: Typo. Fixed.

Comment: how did you install phantomjs?

Comment: Through the binary at http://phantomjs.org/download.html

Comment: I'm also seeing this issue. Any updates as to if/how you fixed it would be great.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same problem to fix it **I installed phantomjs from source**.

```
For Linux (Debian):
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential chrpath git-core libssl-dev libfontconfig1-dev libxft-dev
git clone git://github.com/ariya/phantomjs.git
cd phantomjs
git checkout 1.9
./build.sh

For Mac os:
git clone git://github.com/ariya/phantomjs.git
cd phantomjs
git checkout 1.9
./build.sh
```

For other systems check the following link
http://phantomjs.org/build.html

```
Optional :
cd bin
chmod +x phantomjs
cp phantomjs /usr/bin/
```

I figured it out because when I read my ghostdriver.log file it said.

```
[ERROR - 2014-09-04T19:33:30.842Z] GhostDriver - main.fail - {"message":"Could not start Ghost Driver","line":82,"sourceId":140145669488128,"sourceURL":":/ghostdriver/main.js","stack":"Error: Could not start Ghost Driver\n    at :/ghostdriver/main.js:82","stackArray":[{"sourceURL":":/ghostdriver/main.js","line":82}]}
```

I was sure that there must be some missing files which, it must be using for some edge cases. So I decided to build from source and its working fine now.

Comment: Building Phantom for OSX is pain in ass. It asks for QT libs.