# Can't launch Selenium + PhantomJS/GhostDriver as Child processes

Tags: node.js, selenium, coffeescript, child-process, ghostdriver

I've got a Node script that I want to use the `child_process` module with to get a **Selenium** server running with PhantomJS's **GhostDriver**.

I've required the module:
`Child = require "child_process"`

And here's how I'm trying to start the server and attach GD to it (in Coffeescript):

```
@Selenium = new Child.exec "java -jar selenium/selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar -role hub -port 4444", (error, stdout, stderr) =>
    console.log stdout
    console.log error if error
@PhantomJS = new Child.exec "phantomjs --webdriver=8080 --webdriver-selenium-grid-hub=http://127.0.0.1:4444", (error, stdout, stderr) =>
    console.log stdout
    console.log error if error
```

The `stdout` for `@PhantomJS` is this:

```
PhantomJS is launching GhostDriver...
[ERROR - 2014-12-10T18:51:27.587Z] GhostDriver - main.fail - {"message":"Could not start Ghost Driver","line":82,"sourceId":4469911104,"sourceURL":":/ghostdriver/main.js","stack":"Error: Could not start Ghost Driver\n    at :/ghostdriver/main.js:82","stackArray":[{"sourceURL":":/ghostdriver/main.js","line":82}]}
```

Additionally, I get this error from that command: `{"killed": false, "code": 1, "signal": null}`

Some notes:

- The Selenium jar file is in fact located at selenium/selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar
- I've tried `npm update`ing just to see if that would make a difference
- It occurred to me that something else might be running on port 4444, so I went ahead and ran `"PORT_NUMBER=4444 | lsof -i tcp:${PORT_NUMBER} | awk 'NR!=1 {print $2}' | xargs kill"` to no avail
- I've tried installing PhantomJS from the source as per [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24578879/selenium-cant-connect-to-ghostdriver-but-only-sometimes) to the same error
- If I run these commands separately, outside of the script, it all works fine

Comment: Nope. I burned the computer. That fixed it real good.

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone *else* has this issue, we solved it using `daemon` to run the child process in the *background* so that the terminal is free to run other commands/scripts.

> **Note**: you will need to install the [`daemon`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/daemon) module from NPM: `npm install daemon --save-dev`
>   (*it has tests + decent usage stats and does what you need/expect*)

Create a file called `selenium_child_process.js` and paste the following code:

```
console.log('Starting Selenium ...');
require('daemon')(); // this will run everything after this line in a daemon:
const exec = require('child_process').exec;
// note: your path to the selenium.jar may be different!
exec('java -jar ./bin/selenium.jar', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (error) {
    console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);
    return;
  }
  if (stdout) {
    console.log(`> ${stdout}`); 
  }
  if (stderr) {
    console.log(`>> ${stderr}`); // handle errors in your preferred way.
  }
});
```

Then run the file with `node selenium_child_process.js` (*in your terminal*)

You now have selenium running as a child (*background*) process on TCP Port 4444.

---

If you want to ***shut down*** the Selenium server, you will need to `kill` the process. We use the following command:

`lsof -n -iTCP:4444 -sTCP:LISTEN -n -l -P | grep 'LISTEN' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9`

> *If you get stuck we're happy to help!*